# Why is Spring Boot dependency injection not working in main method?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, dependency-injection

I am sorry for asking a stupid question and you may delete it later if you find it too stupid, but I want to know why dependency injection in Spring Boot is not working inside `main` method? This is my first spring boot project at my job as entry level junior programmer so that is probably the reason why this question is so stupid. Anyway, I have been tasked with developing a data access repository for a table in a database by using spring boot and jpa.
So I created jpa class (E), which, for simplicity i shortened and let us say my jpa class is as follows:

```
package P;
@javax.persistence.Entity()
public class E
{
    @javax.persistence.Id()
    private int I;
}
```

So, nothing special, as basic jpa entity as possible.
Next, I defined repository for this entity (R) and simplified it as follows:

```
package P;
public interface R extends org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository<P.E, Integer>{}
```

Now the good part: Spring boot documentation says that the repository implementation can be autogenerated by using dependency injection. So I tried to test this with the following class (A), which I shortened here for simplicity:

```
package P;
@org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication()
public class A
{
    @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired()
    static P.R F;
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] U)
    {
        org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(P.A.class, "");
        System.out.println(P.A.F);
    }
}
```

So, the class `A` is the main class which starts spring boot application. What I would like to do here is to manage my database inside the `main` method. I wanted to use the dependency injection for my repository interface `R`, so I declared static field (F) in `A` class and annotated it with `Autowired` in order to trigger the injection. In ideal case, what I would expect to happen after I ran Spring Boot in my `main` method (by calling `run()`) is that `F` field of my main class would be injected with the repository class `R` so that I could continue working with data base in my main method. However it is not. `println` method prints `null`.

Now, my question is not "what did I do wrong", I know that. I found on a lot of places on Internet that I can not use a dependency injection directly in the `main` method, but that I instead need to make a Bean. So, for example, I could add the following method (M) in my main class:

```
    @org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
    public boolean M(P.R R)
    {
        System.out.println(R);
        return true;
    }
```

and this would work just fine, it would inject the repository after I annotate it with `Bean` in order to trigger injection. But this is called from inside the `run()` method in my main method, so, if I use this approach, I can not do anygthing inside my `main` method. Whole job which my application does needs to be done inside one or more Beans. At least job which requires the dependency injection. I can do other stuff in the `main` method before and after I run the Spring Boot, but not anything for what I need dependency injection.

So, my qestion here is why spring boot can not inject the repository in my `main` method, that is, outside of a Bean?
I would not say anything if I called `println` before the `run` in my main method. Then of course, `F` field would be `null` since Spring Boot did not start yet. But after it starts, I would like it to inject the repository in the `F` field and that repository stays injected after `run` method returns so that I can work with it inside the `main` method without having to create Beans.

I know that I have to use Beans, just, I want to know what is the reason for it not working in the `main` method as well. Thank you.

Comment: I can't give a definite answer but think about order: your main method is the _entry point_ into the application and `SpringApplication.run()` will be starting Spring and any autowiring that comes with it. However, field `F` is static and already initialized when class `A` is loaded (which must happen before `main()` can be executed). Also note that autowiring on static fields isn't generally supported (at least to my knowledge).

Comment: You cannot autowire static fields, this has been answered in the other question (or the comments) of the duplicate question as well. More info also on https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null.

Comment: Thank you. I was not aware of the static field limitation.